# Amazon Web Service Usage for Zend Framework 1.11.11

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-web-services

I am trying to seach/display books using Amazon Web Service with Zend Framework.

The examples on [this page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.amazon.html) don't work due to change of Amazon API. I think I need to provide my Associate Tag from now on, but I don't know how.

I use the keys that I get from :
https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/securityCredentials

Can anyone show me how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fix for the Amazon API update should be in the next mini-release of ZF. If you can't wait for that, you can apply the patch here: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-12046 to your copy of 1.11.11 to fix the error relating to AWS version you're probably getting.

The AssociateTag requirement was actually a separate backwards-incompatible change Amazon made before the above. You can provide this as an additional param to itemSearch, e.g.:

```
$amazon = new Zend_Service_Amazon('AMAZON_API_KEY', 'US', 'AMAZON_SECRET_KEY');
$results = $amazon->itemSearch(array(
    'SearchIndex' => 'Books',
    'Keywords' => 'php',
    'AssociateTag' => 'yourtaghere'
));
```